# Dereference of a possibly null reference

Tags: reference, null

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

Dereference of a possibly null reference in the User.Identity part of this code. I get an error. How can i solve it? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's warning you, quite rightly, that there's the potential for `User.Identity` to be null, in which case trying to access the `IsAuthenticated` property would throw an exception.

I'm still in the early days of getting to grips with .NET 6 and these nullable warnings are new to me, but this is how I've handled this particular case:

```
@if (User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

What I'm doing here is saying "If `User.Identity` is null, the result of the conditional should be `false`".